# Visual Studio 2015, build cordova projects is very slow

Tags: cordova, build, visual-studio-2015

I'm building a Cordova(5.1.1) project in VS 2015 with a size of about 10Mb, but the time for complete a build is very unacceptable, it's about minutes in a i5 machine with 4GB of ram and SSD.

The task: "Generating config.xml from defaults for Platform ..." takes minutes to be completed.

And there is no way to make live changes...  so the development time began to be too expansive.

There are some tricks to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the problem is ckeditor that have many files (over 2000), so many files in www folder make build task very loooong. Strange that every build need so huge time with the same files...